# Python find and remove between tags

Tags: python, regex

I have some code in a string;

```
/*
* REMOVE ME
*
* */
blah
more blah
/*
* REMOVE ME
*
* */
```

Using python 2.7 I need to remove the text between the tags.

Thanks

Comment: Have you actually research, tried anything?

Comment: Do the tags always start with /*?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive

Comment: Is there any chance that the comments are nested? For example, `/* REMOVE /* nested comment */ ME */`.

Comment: My interpretation is that you want to remove everything from the first /* REMOVE ME*/ to the second one. In other words, in your example, the lines with `blah` and `more blah` would be removed. How do you know which tag is the start and which is the end? Or do you trust that they always come in pairs?

Comment: That1Guy, have you considered that the question comes from someone who is not as confident in their attempts? The internet is such a wonderful place but sullied by those on forums who feel forums is their opportunity to belittle others. I have tried a number of options to little effect including regular expressions none of which needed to be repeated by what was essentially a regular expression question. I note that you have asked similar basic questions in the past without coding examples that were voted down; perhaps you should remember how that felt! Many thank for the helpful comments!

Comment: @ChrisLuff I was not belittling anybody. I was not rude, nor was I implying you hadn't attempted to solve your own problem. I was trying to be helpful and explain the mentality of the majority of users on StackOverflow. I advised you to include your attempts to demonstrate your effort. Regardless of your confidence, a good question should include code examples of attempted solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
s = """\
/*
* REMOVE ME
*
* */
blah
more blah
/*
* REMOVE ME
*
* */"""
re.sub("/\*[\S\s]*?\*/", "", s)
```

Comment: Should `[\S\s]*` not just be `.*`?

Comment: @OGHaza - Yes, that would be better.  However, you will also need to set the dot-all flag so that `.` matches newlines.

Comment: @iCodez Ahhhh.. it all become clear. Newlines.

Comment: Many thanks, the regular expression is what I had tried and failed to get right!

Answer (score 1):

try this simple regex:

```
/[*].*?[*]/
```

explain:

> ***`.`*** Wildcard: Matches any single character.
>
> ***`*`*** Matches the previous element zero or more times.
>
> ***`?`*** Matches the previous element zero or one time.
>
> ***`[character_group]`*** Matches any single character in `character_group`.